# Upper bound on a sum of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Let $A=\{z_1, z_2, z_3,\ldots \} $ be a set of complex numbers with $|z_j|\ge 1$ such that the number of elements of $A$ with modulus $<r$, denoted $N_A(r)$, satisfies 
$$
N_A(r) \le C_0r^N
$$ 
for some positive integer $N$ where $C_0$ is some constant. For any $\delta >0$ I wish to prove an inequality of the form
$$
\sum _{\substack{z_j\in A \\ |z_j| <r}}\frac{1}{|z_j|^{N+\delta }} \le \eta  r,
$$
where $0<\eta <1$. 
Is this even true and in that case could anyone share a hint as how to show it?

Comment: Assume that $r=1$, and that $A = (\epsilon,2,2,.....)$ with $\epsilon<<1$. Then, the bound on $N_A$ holds true ($C_0=1$ and $N=0$). But, the bound on the sum is not true.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I suppose I simplified the problem too much. Instead of $|z_j|$ I actually have $\sqrt{1 + |z_j|^2}$, so assume all $|z_j|\ge 1$.

Comment: I see. It would be better if you will edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is true. Since this problem is approximation so I will not comment exact number. And we use $C$. In probelm, we don't need to use complex number.

Fix $N$. Then $r$-ball contains $Cr^N$ integer points in $ {\bf R}^N$.

So given quantity $\sum \frac{1}{|z_j|^{N+\delta }}$ is approximately $$ C\int_{B_r(0)} 
\frac{1}{|x|^{N+\delta}} t^{N-1} dt d\theta = C\int_0^r \frac{1}{t^{1+\delta}}\ dt = Cr^{-\delta}\leq \eta r$$